# Working method to deploy iPhone app on jailbroken device without developer ID

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, deployment, jailbreak

Is it possible to do?

I have XCode 4.5.2 and jailbroken iphone 4 with ios 5.1.1. I have read a bunch of ways to do that with cydia tweak, self sign certificate, etc. What is the best way to do that if it's possble of course on my config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking at the link below as it is really easy to use:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0JS0D2tXGY

Comment: This path in step 7 is invalid for me: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/iPhoneOS Build System Support.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/iPhoneCodeSign.xcspec

Comment: Try the new link above for a video tutorial.